# C++ Uint8 datatype conversion to const char* datatype

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I need this conversion, because I am working with libraries and want to keep their definitions, but have to make them working together.

so i have

```
functionX(uint8 *src, uint16 nSrcLen){
  write(src);
}

write(const char msg){}
```

thanks for helping out ;)

**edit:** additional infos

functionX and write should, if anyway possible stay this way. However, regardless of this, I am interested in *better* solutions.

*src* will carry null-bytes

**edit:** write, how it used to be used

```
std::string hex_chars;
std::getline(std::cin, hex_chars);
std::istringstream hex_chars_stream(hex_chars);

unsigned int ch;
while (hex_chars_stream >> std::hex >> ch)
{
 write(ch);
}
```

now, there is no need for the hex-conversion anymore, but I guess it is still necessary to use this stream-construction

**edit:** current solution

```
for(uint16 i = 0; i < nSrcLen; i++)
{
    write(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(src)[i]);
    //printf("%d",reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(src)[i]);    
}
```

works for me, for now - thank you guys!

Comment: @ronalchn pointed me in some directions, and I think a quick solution for me would be to step trough *src* using *nSrcLen* to *write* each character in *src* - I am working on this right now, but please, beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the pointer types, you just need to cast the pointer from one type to the other.

For example,

```
uint8 *uint8_pointer = ?;

// C style cast
const char *char_pointer = (char*)uint8_pointer;

// newer C++ style cast syntax
const char *char_pointer2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(uint8_pointer);
```

You can also do it the other way round:

```
char *char_pointer = ?;
uint8 *uint8_pointer = reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(char_pointer);
```

For your function, you can use:

```
functionX(uint8 *src, uint16 nSrcLen){
  write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(src));
}
void write(const char* msg);
```

Comment: it's not that I want to make a function - the functions are going to be used this way, because write is a function of one "lib", functionX is part of another. So i get _unit8 *_ and have to pass it as _const char_

Comment: Ah, I see, giving example in my answer. I'm assuming that the function prototype you gave in your question had a typo (should be `const char*` instead of `const char`).

Comment: it worked - kind of - using `const char *char_pointer = (char*)src;` and `write((*char_pointer))` - but write did only get the first character, not the whole string. any ideas?

Comment: a C type string `char*` automatically terminates on a null byte. Is the 2nd character a `null` AKA "\0" byte?

Comment: ohoh - this might become a problem - there are null byte, will be, and have to be - I guess there is no way, without modifying _write_ and _functionX_? I would prefer to not modify them - especially _functionX_ should stay this way.

Comment: it depends on what function you use on the C type string. When I said automatically terminates, it doesn't really. It is just that C string functions **assume** that it terminates on a null byte. If you have your own functions that know the true length, you can read the whole string even if it has null bytes (in that case, you might want to pass the string length as another argument to `write` though).

Comment: Basically, you can use a `for () {}` loop to read all elements in the char array, if given the length. You just can't easily `printf()` the string to make sure the string is there. If you need to `printf()` the string, instead, try `for (int i=0;i<len;i++) printf("%d ",msg[i])` or similar to print them as integers

Comment: I don't think you can `static_cast<char*>(unsigned char*)` in C++. You'd need to use `reinterpret_cast<>` for that.